# Arduino dies after activating a 5th led

Tags: arduino, led, led-matrix

I have an Arduino Uno, using a MAX7219 to control a 8x8 Bi-color led matrix.

The problem however, is that upon activating a 5th led in the matrix, the unit "dies", in lack of a better word. I can activate any arbitrary combination of 4 leds, but upon the activation of a fifth, the matrix flashes promptly and goes blank.

What kind of problem does this sound like? Improper resistor value? Grounding or inadequate power?

UPDATE: Upon disconnecting the wire grounding the breadboard to the Arduino, all the desired leds are lighting up in my expected pattern, except with a low-intensity brightness.

UPDATE 2: Fritzing didn't have a resembling matrix model, and I'm not doing this by hand now. I have wired (to my understanding) like in [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Main/MAX72XX_Schematic.jpg) schematic, with both the 5V and RSet coming from the MAX7219 onto the power line of the breadboard, RSet via a 10k resistor.

Here are two pictures of the current setup: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDdhP.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uov8U.jpg).
2 ground wires as per the [MAX7219 Datasheet](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf), DIG0-7 on columns, SEGDP-G on rows, RSet to 5V via 10k resistor and normal 5V.

I am obviously new to this and I don't mean to ask stupid questions so please be patient.

Are there any logical flaws in these pictures?

Comment: A schematic would be most appreciated

Comment: Haven't made one yet, gimme a few.

Comment: Downvoted because "gimme" isn't a proper word!

Comment: Added a link to the schematic I followed.

Comment: What are you using to power everything?

Comment: The 5V input on the Arduino board itself.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like a inadequacy of power to me based on the information you've provided. I believe this to be so due to a similar experience with a Dot-Matrix display. I was able to light only so many blue LEDs, until the power supply cut the power for overload protection. Upon upgrading to a 5 ampere power supply, I no longer experienced that issue.

Comment: This answer may well be correct based on the minimal information that was provided, so why the downvote? +1 from me.

Comment: nice and succinct answer from a newbie, nice work.

Comment: Updated my question. If you got further insight it will be appreciated.